# Cleaning data by replacing large set of values with reduced set of values in R

Tags: r, data-cleaning

I am working with a data set where a particular field has many possible values, but I want to clean the values to a reduced set of values.
As an example, an application is either approved or denied,
but they are recorded in the database with different text strings.
How do I clean it so that I get clean output?

```
the_status <- c('2: approved (newer)',
                '5: approved (extended)',
                '3: denied (not appealed)',
                '14: denied (not appealed/withdrawn)',
                '20: approved',
                '21: denied',
                '24: not approved within 21 days',
                '28: not approved in 21 days')

data.frame(candidate_id = 1:8,
           status = the_status)
```

What I want:

```
data.frame(candidate_id = 1:8,
           status = c('approved', 'approved', 'denied',
                      'denied', 'approved', 'denied',
                      'denied', 'denied'))
```

**Note:** In the real data set, there are about 100,000 rows,
and there are about 30 different strings for the field `status`,
which I want to reduce into about 4 values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do this:

1. Determine the list of unique possible status `unique(the_status)`
2. Code them by hand :

   ```
   code <- data.frame(orig_status=unique(the_status),
                      new_status=c("approved","denied",...)) 
   # You have to do this step manually
   ```
3. merge the datasets

Example:

```
set.seed(50)
raw_data <- data.frame(orig_status=sample(the_status,replace=TRUE,100),
                       id=1:100)


code <- data.frame(orig_status=unique(raw_data$orig_status),
                   new_status=c('denied','denied',
                                'approved','denied',
                                'approved','approved',
                                'denied','denied'))

code
clean_data <- merge(raw_data,code)
```

Coding 30 unique values by hand is likely to be much faster than looking for a programmatic way to do it.

Comment: I’d do a hybrid approach that includes some automatic cleanup (I’ve done this successfully in the past) but apart from that, the general idea of using an exhaustive list of possibilities is in my experience the best way.

Answer (score 1):

We can change the 'not approved' to 'denied' and then extract using `sub`.

```
df1$status <-  sub('[^:]+\\:\\s*(\\S+).*', '\\1', 
                sub('not approved', 'denied', df1$status))
```

Comment: I added more examples, basically the status can also be "not approved" which I want to map into "denied" as well. Unfortunately your regular expression substitution doesn't work with such entries.

Comment: @ILiketoCode  Updated the code.  Anyway, it is better to show an example that mimics the original dataset.

Answer (score 1):

you can do it with `merge()`:

```
d <- data.frame(candidate_id = 1:8, status = the_status)
red.tab <- data.frame(candidate_id = 1:8,
           status = c('approved', 'approved', 'denied',
                      'denied', 'approved', 'denied',
                      'denied', 'denied'))
merge(d, red.tab, by="candidate_id")
```

Comment: I added a detail that I have about 100000 IDs so I can't manually determine the cleaned status.

Comment: But you have a table with the original codes (example: `'24: ...'` and the new codes `'denied'`), or not? I think you must have; and then you can do the `merge(...)`

Comment: This table is not given to me, but I could make such a table.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution.

```
the_status <- c('2: approved (newer)',
                '5: approved (extended)',
                '3: denied (not appealed)',
                '14: denied (not appealed/withdrawn)',
                '20: approved',
                '21: denied',
                '24: not approved within 21 days',
                '28: not approved in 21 days')
```

Split the data one by one using sapply, strsplit and unlist commands.

```
x = sapply(the_status, function(t){ a = unlist(strsplit(t, ": ")); 
                                    b = unlist(strsplit(a[2], " \\("));
                                    c(a[1],b[1]) })
```

It returns a matrix.

```
>t(x)
                                    [,1] [,2]                         
2: approved (newer)                 "2"  "approved"                   
5: approved (extended)              "5"  "approved"                   
3: denied (not appealed)            "3"  "denied"                     
14: denied (not appealed/withdrawn) "14" "denied"                     
20: approved                        "20" "approved"                   
21: denied                          "21" "denied"                     
24: not approved within 21 days     "24" "not approved within 21 days"
28: not approved in 21 days         "28" "not approved in 21 days"
```

Convert it to data.frame and set names.

```
df = data.frame(t(x))
rownames(df) = NULL
colnames(df) = c("candidate_id", "status")
```

Here is the result.

```
df
  candidate_id                      status
1            2                    approved
2            5                    approved
3            3                      denied
4           14                      denied
5           20                    approved
6           21                      denied
7           24 not approved within 21 days
8           28     not approved in 21 days
```

If you don't want the original IDs you can simply change them as follows:

```
df$candidate_id = 1:nrow(df$candidate_id)
```

or

```
df$candidate_id = rownames(df)
```